# Python Concatenation

Tags: python, concatenation

This issue is probably very easy but I can't figure it out -

I have the following values: `['2000']['09']['22']`

I want the following: `20000922` or `'20000922'`

***code***

```
def transdatename(d):
    year = re.findall('\d\d\d\d', str(d))
    premonth = re.findall('[A-Z][a-z]{2,9}', str(d))
    month = replace_all(str(premonth), reps)
    daypre = re.findall('\d{1,2},', str(d))
    day = re.sub(',','', str(daypre))
    fulldate = str(year)+str(month)+str(day)
    return fulldate
```

**Example data**

**Input:**
['\nSeptember 23, 2000']

**Expected Output:** '20000922'

Comment: **['2000']['09']['22']** - what is it? A string? A list?

Comment: @user831880 It's hard for us to help, because we're not sure what you mean by `['2000']['09']['22']`. Can you edit your question to include code from some of your attempts from either the Python interpreter or your .py file?

Comment: I'm not sure what it is! I'm trying to concatenate 3 values which I think should result in a long string but it isn't working. I've added the code to the original post.

Comment: Please give us input and expected output

Comment: I have added example input and output above. Thank you!!

Comment: day is string, year is list, month is ???

Comment: removed my -1 as you were willing to clarify your question.

Comment: Is that a typo, or do you expect to translate '23' in the input to '22' in the ouput?

Answer (score 4):

Are you trying to do this?

```
>>> input= '\nSeptember 23, 2000'
>>> format= '\n%B %d, %Y'
>>> datetime.datetime.strptime(input,format)
datetime.datetime(2000, 9, 23, 0, 0)
>>> (_+datetime.timedelta(-1)).strftime("%Y%m%d")
'20000922'
```

If so, you're making it too hard.

Comment: Thank you for this answer. I was in the middle of trying to implement a solution given above but it wasn't working for me. Your solution here showed me what I was doing wrong and the problem is now fixed. Thank you!!

Answer (score 2):

Use [itertools.chain](http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html?highlight=chain#itertools.chain):

```
from itertools import chain    
data = [['2000'],['09'],['22']]   
''.join(chain(*data))
#OR
int(''.join(chain(*data))) # for numeric value representation
```

OR [functools.reduce](http://docs.python.org/library/functools.html?highlight=reduce#functools.reduce):

```
data = [['2000'],['09'],['22']]   
''.join(reduce(lambda res,x: res+x, data))
```

AND:

```
''.join(''.join(x) for x in data)
```

At least in case you mentioned a list, tuple, set of lists:

```
initList = [['2000'],['09'],['22']]   
resultList = []
for subList in initList:
   resultList.append(''.join(subList))

outputValue = ''.join(resultList)
intValue = int(outputValue)
```

After reading your code i think that it could be done the following way:

```
str_dates = ['\nSeptember 23, 2000']
monthMap = {'January': 1, 'February': 2, ....}
month, day, year str_dates[0].lstrip('\n').split()
year + monthMap[month] + day[:-1]
```

OR - think is the best way:

```
from datetime import datetime
str_dates = ['\nSeptember 23, 2000']
[datetime.strptime(sDate,'%B %d, %Y').strftime('%Y%d%m') for sDate in str_dates]
```

Sure that you can use regex - but i am not sure that this is the most apropriate way here, however if you want to use it it would be better to use single - something like this(it just a sample code it thre should be a better regex expression):

```
yearData = re.findall(r'(?i)^([a-z]{2,9})\s(\d{1,2}),\s(\d{2,4}$)', 'September 23, 2000')
#yearData contains now [('September', '23', '2000')]
```

Comment: @Kirk - thank you - but there are still some downvoters withot comenting on reason.

Comment: -1.  You're assuming you know what he means by ['2000']['09']['22'].  Also, judging from the question, these answers are way too complicated for the questioner to even begin to understand.

Comment: Using itertools or reduce is very unnecessary here -1, for your last solution seems clear +1, so no votes.

Comment: @utdemir- i simply give an options for a questioner

Comment: @Steven, @utdemir: I disagree in that @Artsiom's answers aren't exactly idiomatic but they're "fun" solutions to an unclear question. I think I used `threading` and `socket` to help someone rename a file once just to see how complicated it could become.

Comment: @Steven Remember that a question may be of use to more people than the original poster. Multiple solutions to the problem are likely to add value.

Comment: @Kirk and @Rob - thank you for understanding, it is always good when there is somebody who can understand you

Comment: Thanks a lot for this advise. I've tried these solutions but they are not working for me. I've included extra code above.

Comment: in your case you need carefully check data types of year, month and day - as far as i know findall returns you a list so the most possible solution here is to use year[0]+month[0]+day[0]. However please print our year, month and day so we would able to get you correct answer. Also it seems to me that it would be better to use one regex instead of 3 or datetime.strptime function here or year, month, day = d.split().

Comment: Hi, when I print the values I get ['2000'] ['09'] ['2000']. I tried using the [0] solutin but I get the folowing error -  "exceptions:IndexError: list index is out of range"

Comment: Thanks very much. I tried using the timedate modle but I'm getting the error - exceptions.ValueError: time data '\nMay 3, 2008' does not match format '%B %d, %Y'

Comment: Artsiom - I just added \n to the pattern you gave above and it worked perfectly. Thank you so much - this problem was driving me crazy!!

Comment: You are welcome, but datetime code can be also modified to match your criteria - for ex datetime.strptime(sDate,"\\n%B %d, %Y").strftime('%Y%d%m')

Answer (score 2):

I assume these are list items?
Like this;

```
a=['2000']
b=['99']
c=['22']
```

If that's right, then

```
a[0]+b[0]+c[0]
```

will do the trick

Comment: I've tried this one but it won't work i'm afriad. I get an error - "exceptions:IndexError: list index is out of range"

Comment: If you type my code, it works :) - however, if the assumptions are wrong, maybe you should be more detailed in your questions in future

Answer (score 0):

```
['2000'][0] + ['09'][0] + ['22'][0]
```

Comment: Downvoter, give it a try. It works an produces the expected results. If you can provide a specific criticism about the _way_ it works, I look forward to your comments.

Comment: -1.  You're assuming you know what he means by `['2000']['09']['22']`

Comment: @Steven: that's rough, c'mon, his assumption sounds very reasonable to me; +1 from me.

Comment: I didn't downvote, but I didn't upvote either. Yes this produces the correct output, but I suspect this one-line answer may not help user831880 much.

Comment: @Jon-Eric: You are correct. It is a very specific answer based on the limited scope of the question. I could have expanded it in the manner @samb8s did in his answer to assign the values to variables and operate on those, but that would have been based on assumptions. This answer is correct for the given scope. The OP can ask about variable assignment and related issues as needed.

Comment: This doesn't work for me. I get the following error - "exceptions:IndexError: list index is out of range"

Answer (score 0):

Here's a couple of approaches of changing `'\nSeptember 23, 2000'` to `'20000923'`:

Using [`strptime`](http://docs.python.org/library/time.html#time.strptime):

```
import time
def transdatename(t):
    # won't work if day of month can be a single digit.  must have leading zero
    return time.strftime('%Y%m%d', time.strptime(t, '\n%B %d, %Y'))

print transdatename('\nSeptember 23, 2000') # prints 20000923
```

Using regex:

```
import re
# use dictionary to convert month name to two digit number
month_to_num = {'January': '01',
        'February': '02',
        'March': '03',
        'April': '04',
        'May': '05',
        'June': '06',
        'July': '07',
        'August': '08',
        'September': '09',
        'October': '10',
        'November': '11',
        'December': '12'}

def transdatename(t):
    month, day, year = re.search('(\w+)\W+(\d+)\W+(\d+)', t).groups()
    month = month_to_num[month]
    # if day could be a single digit use day.zfill(2)
    return year + month + day

print transdatename('\nSeptember 23, 2000') # prints 20000923
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for this! I ended up using the datetime module to do the tranformation instead of regex.